# How to convert an http.get.("URL").subscribe to a promise so that I can await it?

Tags: promise, async-await, subscribe

How can I convert the http.get.subscribe to await so that I can wait for it before going on to the next code?
The problematic function is this:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.setupIngredients();

    console.log("this text should be displayed after FINISHED");
    otherCode();
    //....other code
}
```

I want the `otherCode()` and the `console.log("this text should be displayed after FINISHED");` to execute after the `setupIngredients()` has finished.

My setupIngredients function is this:

```
setupIngredients() {
    this.indicatorDataService.http.get(this.baseGetUrl + "entity=ingredients&indicator=all").subscribe(res => {
        // do something with res


    });
}
```

I still don't know why it won't convert to a correct Promise. I tried replacing the subscribe with toPromise, but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by wrapping the subscribe into a Promise like this:

```
setupIngredients() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.indicatorDataService.http.get(this.baseGetUrl + "entity=ingredients&indicator=all").subscribe(res => {
            // do something with res
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```